# I am facing arabic text issue in flutter can any one solve it?

Tags: android, flutter

```
                     Text(
                      'ٱقۡرَأۡ بِٱسۡمِ رَبِّكَ ٱلَّذِى خَلَقَ ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: CustomColors.orange,
                      ),
          
      ),
```

In this  word is رَبِّكَ but it appears different on a mobile screen
like  [رَبِّكَ appears different you can see in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ55c.jpg)

Comment: Nothing is wrong! the second رَبِّكَ in the picture has ل before it in Quran too.

Comment: yes I know, this is  perfect but issue in text format  appearing

Comment: you can see here ( rabi )  https://ayatinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/The-virtue-of-reading-the-surah-al-Fatihah.jpg

Comment: it's just text apprearing issue, try changing font and see the text https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiri+Quran?preview.text=%D9%B1%D9%82%DB%A1%D8%B1%D9%8E%D8%A3%DB%A1%20%D8%A8%D9%90%D9%B1%D8%B3%DB%A1%D9%85%D9%90%20%D8%B1%D9%8E%D8%A8%D9%91%D9%90%D9%83%D9%8E%20%D9%B1%D9%84%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%B0%D9%90%D9%89%20%D8%AE%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%8E%D9%82%D9%8E